# Elasticsearch exact match for each word in text

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search text in the following order and give relevence score accordingly:

> 1. match for exact phrase
> 2. All words (exact word) should appear in search result
> 3. some or atleast one word should appear in result

Here is my query:

```
{
  "_source": [
    "title"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "introduction to java",
              "fuzziness": 0,
              "operator": "and",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": {
              "query": "introduction to java",
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "size": 20
}
```

But I am getting Javascript or jQuery first instead of java.
Result:

```
{
"_score": 594.7316,
"_source": {
"title": "Introduction to jQuery Web Development"
}
}
,
{
"_score": 592.86993,
"_source": {
"title": "Introduction to JavaScript Development"
}
}
,
{
"_score": 592.8397,
"_source": {
"title": "A Comprehensive Introduction to Java Virtual Machine (JVM)"
}
}
,
{
"_score": 591.7474,
"_source": {
"title": "Introduction to Java for Programmers"
}
}
```

What should I do to make this happen ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query works fine for me - except that using `"operator": "and"` will break your third rule of including results that contain at least one of the terms in it (change it to "or" or just remove it).  
Maybe try using the [Explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html) option to see how your results are being scored.

Comment: explain option is nice. I got something:
"description": "weight(title:"(i in int intr intro introd introdu introduc introduct introducti introductio introduction) (t to) (j ja jav java)" in 5759) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:"

It is searching for any one of edge ngram here.
but I'm not using any ngram analyzer here

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this one is my mistake.
I applied edge_ngram analyzer on title field using mapping api so thats why it was searching for j/ja/jav/java.

I deleted the index and created a new one without this mapping and its working fine for me.